# Linker error after upgrading to Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode

my code was working well with sdk 4.2 but while upgrading the sdk and the xcode to 4 it raise error apple mach-o error

and this is its details

> bad codegen, pointer diff in
>   itk::ProcessAborted::ProcessAborted(char
>   const*, unsigned int)to global weak
>   symbol vtable for
>   itk::ProcessAbortedfor architecture
>   armv7 collect2: ld returned 1 exit
>   status Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

any suggestion to solve this issue ,

itk is a library I built using xcode and g++4.2

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a complete clean and re-build of the project? Xcode 4 uses LLVM as its default compiler, not g++. If you have part of the project -- or old object files -- kicking around from a g++ build, I could imagine that you might well run into trouble...

Comment: I did clean and build , but it give the above error , I cannot find from where I can change the compiling options is there a tutorial to change from LIVM to g++

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you open your project in Xcode, click on the project in the far left pane to bring up the project settings in the main window, choose "Build Settings" in the gray bar at the top, and scroll down to the "Compiler Version" group, you should be able to see which compiler Xcode is trying to use to build your project. LLVM should handle most standard C/C++/Obj-C projects without any significant code changes (unless you're doing some really low-level or unusual stuff).

Comment: That's...weird. How much trouble would it be for you to create a new Xcode 4 project and re-import the class and resource files and update the Framework dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Try *File > Workspace Settings* ( or *Project Settings* ) and enter the following settings:

- Derived Data (index, logs, build) Location

  - Custom > Workspace-relative path > 'DerivedData'
- Build Location

  - Place build products in derived data location

    - Custom Subfolder

This worked for me as my nested projects/libraries we not getting linked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with the same problem and finally found a solution:

In Build settings, ensure that "C/C++ Compiler Version" is set to "GCC 4.2" and "Symbols Hidden by Default" is set to "YES"

**Then search for "*Optimization Level*" and change it to "*None [-O0]*"**

If it doesn't work, look at the build settings of your target and check that the same options/values are set